# Set a tabIndex on an Reactstrap component

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, reactstrap

I am trying to set a tab index on a link in React. The render function of my component looks like this:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Nav tabs>
          <NavItem tabIndex={1}>
            <NavLink
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggle('1');
              }}
              tabIndex='1'
            >
              {this.props.tabText01}
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
...
```

As you can see, I have tried to set a tabIndex on both the NavItem and I have also tried on the NavLink (which come from reactstrap), but nothing is showing when I inspect the links on my browser tools.

When tabbing across the page, there is a pause when I tab over the two NavItems that I have, so it's like it's registering it (i.e. I have to tab twice to get to an element after my nav) however it is not showing up in the markup, and the items do not visually appear to be selected.

Any pointers as to how I can make this tab accessible will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `tabIndex='1'` from `NavLink`, and  `NavItem` must have `tabIndex='1'` as a string.

Comment: @ravibagul91 these are now tab-able but they are still not keyboard accessible as when I hit enter, the link isn't visited - do you know how I can make them link on enter please?